# Convert DateTime data into MM/DD/YYYY in Jquery

Tags: jquery, sql-server

I'm storing a Date-time data into the SQL Server using a date-picker.  Now I tried to retrieve that data, but it's coming as follows, **"/Date(1573065000000)/"**.

```
function populateDate(data) {
    $("#date").val(data.issuedate)
}
```

Above code is using to retrive **date** from the db. I need to convert this to get the date as follows, **11/07/2019**.

Comment: Why was it stored as `/Date(1573065000000)/` and not as a date in the first place?

Comment: No, the date store in the db as follows,  `2019-11-07`, but when I retrieve it, it comes as  `/Date(1573065000000)/`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your sql SELECT statement

```
SELECT 
   DATE_FORMAT(date_column, '%d/%m/%Y')
FROM table_name;
```

Comment: Can you help me to change my function in order to convert and get the date as I want.